# Cisco 877 as PPPoA/PPPoE bridge (no routing) - how to make it listen to IP for management?

Tags: cisco, bridge, pppoe, pppoa

I have a Cisco 877 configured to bridge ADSL with PPPoA to PPPoE on Vlan1. This works fine, but in this mode the only way I can configure the Cisco is via the serial console. I'd like to have the Cisco also listen on an IP address so I can telnet/ssh into it. I think the right way to go about this would be via `bridge irb`, but I'm not sure exactly how (or if that's even the right direction). IOS is 12.4T and my current config (cut down to essentials) is:

```
no ip routing
no ip cef
!
!
interface ATM0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
 pvc 0/38 
  encapsulation aal5snap
 !
 dsl operating-mode auto 
 bridge-group 1
!
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 bridge-group 1
```

Just setting an IP address on Vlan1 didn't have the desired effect, but surely this must be possible somehow (the Draytek Vigor 120 even does it by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a BVI interface and give the desired IP address to it. Don't forget to add:

```
bridge 1 protocol ieee
bridge 1 route ip
```

note:
before create BVI interface you must use this command:

```
bridge irb
```

Comment: Here's the whole working config I ended up with: https://sdfjkl.org/blog/cisco-877-as-adsl-modem/