# Connect from firewall to Cisco 877 in Bridged mode

Tags: networking, cisco, modem, adsl

I have a Cisco 877 in bridged mode acting as an ADSL2 modem only. My firewall is doing PPPOE and the internet works great.

What I would like to do is give vlan1 on the Cisco 877 an IP address e.g. 10.10.10.1/24 and then give my firewall a secondary WAN IP of 10.10.10.2 so that I can connect to the Cisco 877 and manage it without having to use the console port (kick off a reboot from the LAN side).

My working bridge config is

```
!
interface ATM0
no ip address
no atm ilmi-keepalive
pvc 8/35
encapsulation aal5snap
!
dsl operating-mode auto
bridge-group 1
!
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
bridge-group 1
!
bridge 1 protocol ieee
!
```

in order to do what I want, I would have thought I could simply add an IP to vlan1 e.g.

```
!
interface ATM0
no ip address
no atm ilmi-keepalive
pvc 8/35
encapsulation aal5snap
!
dsl operating-mode auto
bridge-group 1
!
!
interface Vlan1
ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
bridge-group 1
!
bridge 1 protocol ieee
!
```

however, this simply does not work. I see nothing in the ARP table on the firewall WAN interface that has a secondary IP of 10.10.10.2

I followed [Cisco 877 as PPPoA/PPPoE bridge (no routing) - how to make it listen to IP for management?](https://serverfault.com/questions/441019/cisco-877-as-pppoa-pppoe-bridge-no-routing-how-to-make-it-listen-to-ip-for-m) which suggests to use

```
bridge irb
```

and then

```
bridge 1 protocol ieee
bridge 1 bridge ip
```

Anyone able to help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a BVI interface and then give that BVI interface an ip address, e.g.:

```
config term
int BVI1
ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

By virtue of putting both adapters in bridge group 1, you've bridged them together.  By creating a BVI1 interface, you allow your router to have an ip address on that same bridge (The number after BVI coincides with the bridge group you've defined)